# how to setup logback for maven tests

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

When I'm running the maven tests from my IntelliJ environment i can see all the application setup logs. I'm working with logback. 
But when I'm running same maven tests on jenkins, there is no output for application logs. 
Thus I have some tests that fails on linux and i have no idea why.

How can I make the logs be printed when i'm running:

```
 mvn clean -DskipTests=false test
```

Comment: Just to make sure: where are you looking for logs on Jenkins?

Comment: If you need logs to debug failed tests it is my opinion that your tests are too complicated.  Unit tests should be simple and clear.

Comment: Usually the logs will be put into the target folder somewhere? Depending on how you defined the logging ?